# Home 4G Broadband Routers - Is The B311 Gateway limited?

Tags: windows, router

Recently i've had a lot of problems with the speed of our internet, which we get with Three in the UK.  They provided a black b311-220 gateway in which I put a sim card and get access to the internet with.

When we first got the router end of of last year, we were getting speeds between 20-40 all the time.  And now its about 20-30.  But in the troubleshooting of the device to get it working, I was asked to take the SIM out of the router and put it into my phone.

It was intermittent, but twice with the speed test I got speeds of 79-80Mbps from my Galaxy S9+.  However in the router I've never seen anything like those speeds.

So is the router limiting the speed of the internet, would another router get better speeds, or is it due  some other fact like wifi connection or something like that?

I would like to see if another router would be faster but they are all upwards of £100+ and I dont want to spend the money if its not going to fix the problem.

Comment: I'd ask 3 if it's even possible first. idk about phone-network modems, but many of the majors, BT, Virgin don't allow 3rd party cable/DSL modems to connect.

Comment: @Tetsujin wow I didnt know that, oka I will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routers have an internal bandwidth limitation. Cheaper routers tend to have lower internal bandwidth; higher grade routers usually have better internal bandwidth.

I had to replace my own router to get better speed. A computer connected directly to the ISP modem got top speed.

So you need to address the router. First try upgrading the firmware and if that does not work, consider replacing it. See if you have a friend that can loan you a router for an hour or so to test before you purchase.